# Оптимизация кода C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, оптимизация

Как можно оптимизировать и/или сократить этот код?

Скрипт подключён к префабу. Суть в том, что при определённом отдалении от игрока (distToPlayer > distToTeleport), объект телепортируется в точку одной из четвертей окружности с радиусом distToTeleport - 5 в зависимости от положения объекта относительно игрока (по сути просто перемещается в другой угол).

```
private void Move()
{
    float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);

    if (distToPlayer > distToStop)
    {
        if (distToPlayer < distToTeleport)
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Player.position.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                if (Player.position.y > transform.position.y)
                {
                    spawnPoint.x = Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
                    spawnPoint.y = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
                    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    spawnPoint.x = Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
                    spawnPoint.y = - Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
                    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Player.position.y > transform.position.y)
                {
                    spawnPoint.x = - Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
                    spawnPoint.y = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
                    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    spawnPoint.x = - Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
                    spawnPoint.y = - Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
                    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итог:

```
private void Move() {
    float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);
    
    if (distToPlayer <= distToStop)
        return;     

    distToPlayer < distToTeleport ? moveToFooFooFoo() : moveToBlaBlaBla();
}

private void moveToFooFooFoo() {
    rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
} 

private void moveToBlaBlaBla() {
    spawnPoint.x = (Player.position.x > transform.position.x ? 1 : -1) * Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
    spawnPoint.y = (Player.position.y > transform.position.y ? 1 : -1) * Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));             
    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;      
}
```

---

Достаточно самому выделить повторяющиеся части вне условий и увидеть, что другие части отличаются лишь знаком +/- . В итоге можно было сократить внутреннюю часть до вот такого момента

```
if (Player.position.x > transform.position.x) {
    spawnPoint.x = Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
    spawnPoint.y = (Player.position.y > transform.position.y ? 1 : -1) * Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;      
} else {
    spawnPoint.x = - Random.Range(0, distToTeleport - 5);
    spawnPoint.y = (Player.position.y > transform.position.y ? 1 : -1) * Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(distToTeleport - 5, 2) - Mathf.Pow(spawnPoint.x, 2));
    transform.position = Player.position + spawnPoint;      
}
```

А потом дальше по аналогии выделять общие части и смотреть что остаётся

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизация это не сокращение кода, напротив, кода может стать больше.

```
[SerializeField] private float _speed = 10;
[SerializeField] private float _maxMoveDistance = 10;
[SerializeField] private float _ringDistance = 10;
private Transform _ringCenter;
private Rigidbody2D _body;

private Vector2 DeltaPosition = transform.position - _ringCenter.position;

private void Move ()
{
    // для сравнения дистанций не нужно вычислять квадратный корень (Vector2.Distance), можно просто сравнить сами квадраты
    bool isMaxDistance = DeltaPosition.sqrMagnitude > _maxMoveDistance * _maxMoveDistance;
    // выделение кода в отдельные медоты дают понятную картину его ответственности, имующую понятное имя
    if (isMaxDistance == false)
        AddForceToBody(Vector2.up);
    else
        TransferToRing(_ringDistance);
}

private void AddForceToBody (Vector2 vector) => _body.AddRelativeForce(vector * _speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

private void StopBody () => _body.velocity = Vector2.zero;

private void TransferToRing (float radius)
{
    StopBody();
    Vector2 deltaPosition = DeltaPosition;
    // вся разница только в знаках, которые тупо можно выразить в множетеле *1 / *-1
    Vector2 axisSign = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(deltaPosition.x), Mathf.Sign(deltaPosition.y));
    Vector2 ringPoint;
    ringPoint.x = Random.Range(0, radius) * axisSign.x;
    // нахождение y, через x с помощью кв. корня разниц радиуса и x, плохой способ
    // внешне вычисления выглядит тоже ужасно
    ringPoint.y = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(radius, 2) - Mathf.Pow(ringPoint.x, 2)) * axisSign.y;
    // с правильным именованием, сами выражения становятся говорящими
    transform.position = _ringCenter.position + ringPoint;
}

// но куда проще найти сегмент через радиану дульта позиции и нет ограничений на количество, как с знаками +/-, хоть 4 сегмента, хоть 10
// но для этого нужно знать геометрию окружности, для видеоигр это вообще обязательно
private void TransferToRing (float radius)
{
    StopBody();
    int segmentCount = 4; // количество сегментов (хотя её нужно вывести в поле класса)
    float segmentRadian = Mathf.PI * 2f / segmentCount; // радиана одного сегмента
    Vector2 deltaPosition = DeltaPosition;
    float deltaRadian = Mathf.Atan2(deltaPosition.y, deltaPosition.x);
    int segment = Mathf.FloorToInt(deltaRadian / segmentRadian); // в каком сегменте дельта позиции
    float newRadian = segment * segmentRadian + Random.Range(0, segmentRadian);
    Vector2 ringPoint = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(newRadian), Mathf.Sin(newRadian)) * radius;
    transform.position = _ringCenter.position + ringPoint;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую теперь в этом разобраться...